# Apache2 can't connect site from outside

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, www

I'm trying to set up an Apache2 wordpress website. Server runs Debian Jessie. I can access the site with local ip but not from outside LAN.

What's wrong with my config files please :

ports.conf

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mysite.net
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I guess something is missing inside those files but can't find what...

Thanx for your help !!

UPDATE : Still not solved and i really don't understand what could be the problem. Tried with Nginx and still no connection from outside.

Strange fact : when i connect from outside using www.mysite.com, nothing happens, but when i connect using www.mysite.com/whatever (www.mysite.com/zzzz) i'm redirected on http server error page "not found on this server", apache or nginx depending which one i'm running. So port forwarding must runs fine. Why is it not working with root directory ???? (eg www.mysite.com/)

Thanx a lot !!!

Comment: Have you opened the ports in your modem/router?

Comment: What happens when you try to connect from the LAN?  Do you get connection refused, or the debian default page?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html), to listen on all interfaces, you should use this:

```
Listen 80
```

So, I suggest you remove the `0.0.0.0:`.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` also means “on all interfaces”.

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin rights to your router , i think you should enable port forwarding such that your server will be accessible from outside through the very same port it is running on.

Comment: Off course it was already enabled !!